# How are multiple account addresses derived from a single public key?

Tags: wallets, addresses, private-key, public-key

The following is an except from [Mastering Ethereum](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/04keys-addresses.asciidoc), but how you can you have multiple accounts in a wallet like MetaMask that manages a single key pair?

Private key *k*:

```
k = f8f8a2f43c8376ccb0871305060d7b27b0554d2cc72bccf41b2705608452f315
```

Public key *K* (*x* and *y* coordinates concatenated and shown as hex):

```
K = 6e145ccef1033dea239875dd00dfb4fee6e3348b84985c92f103444683bae07b83b5c38e5e...
```

We use Keccak-256 to calculate the *hash* of this public key:

```
Keccak256(K) = 2a5bc342ed616b5ba5732269001d3f1ef827552ae1114027bd3ecf1f086ba0f9
```

Then we keep only the last 20 bytes (least significant bytes), which is our Ethereum address:

```
001d3f1ef827552ae1114027bd3ecf1f086ba0f9
```

Comment: there is one private key to manage/unlock the wallet, but each account in the wallet has its own private key

Comment: @sola24 so it's like a HD wallet in bitcoin?

Comment: @MatthewCruz Exactly. Ethereum uses HD wallets with it own derivation path m’/44’/60’/0’/0, see https://help.myetherwallet.com/en/articles/5867305-hd-wallets-and-derivation-paths.